# Calling an Apex action that isn't in Lightning Project

Tags: lightning-web-components

i'm trying to call the selected apex class from my function.

#### HTML

```
<template if:true={apexclass.data}>
        <template for:each={apexclass.data} for:item="apex">
                <lightning-input type="checkbox" key={apex.Id} label={apex.Name}></lightning-input>
        </template>
</template>`
```

#### JS

```
import { LightningElement,wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getClass from "@salesforce/apex/SchedulableClasses.SchedulableClasses";
export default class LightningExampleInputDateTime extends LightningElement {
    @wire (getClass) apexclass;`
```

I'm using these two html and javascript with addition to an apex class to get the schedulable classes i want. But i'm having a problem with execution process to these classes. my question is, is it possible to call an apex action that is outside my project without trying to import each of them one by one?

Comment: The HTML + JS looks ok. 

What do you mean by "outside my project?"

To invoke an Apex method you must import it from the scoped module `@salesforce/apex/...`

Comment: You parse the return of Apex function?

Comment: @KevinVenkiteswaran oh okay i was trying to make sure that built in functions aren't also auraenabled

Comment: @RamiAbouKhalil can you give an example of a “built in function?”

Comment: @KevinVenkiteswaran for example the interface schedulable